# UITableView --> Editing mode

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I have an `IBAction` with a `UIButton` that enables the edit mode. I'd like to hit the same `UIButton` and cancel the edit mode. If I use an `if-else` statement, what do I check for : `if(editeModeEnabled)//turn it off, else turn it on` ... so I can use the same `UIButton` for both on and off.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for the `tableView.editing == YES`

eg:

```
if(self.tableView.editing)
//Turn editing off/save changes
else
{
    //Turn editing on
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, Dermot! I used if ([<tableViewname> isEditing] == YES). I didn't know tableView has a property for this. :D

Answer (score 5):

If the button is a bar button item, then the easiest way to toggle the edit button is to set the bar button item to the pre-configured editButtonItem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

This special button automatically toggles between "Edit" and "Done"; it also puts the table view in editing mode.

Comment: Hi @bilobatum, is not. Is just a regular button. I already have an IBAction for it (onClick).Thanks.

Comment: No custom button needed.  This is the superior answer.